# How can I display the name of the prpt file on a report in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: pentaho

This maybe simple but I am trying to display the name of the report(.prpt file) in the Page footer section of the Pentaho report. Is there any way to do this in the Pentaho Report Designer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a function type "Open Formula" and its field called Formula write `=DOCUMENTMETADATA("http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"; "title")` then just add a text-field and add it whichever section you want.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the reply. This does give me the title of the report that I have declared in the Report properties. What I was looking at was if I could display the name of the prpt file and not the title( how the report is saved with .prpt extension)